# How do I generate random buttons based on my data coming from API request?

Tags: reactjs, axios

So, I am making a quiz application, in which the questions and answers are fetched from an API using `axios`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';

const axios = require('axios').default;

const PlayQuiz = () => {
    // declaring all the state here
    const [questionsArray, setQuestionsArray] = useState([]);

    // Using effects here
    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            method: 'get', 
            url: 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10',
        }).then(res => {setQuestionsArray(Object.values(res.data)[1])})
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {console.log('questions array', questionsArray)}, [questionsArray]);

    // Returning html markup here 
    return (<>
        <div className = 'questions-container'>
            {questionsArray[0]? <h1>{questionsArray[0].question}</h1> : ''}
        </div>
    </>)
}


export default PlayQuiz;
```

This code just basically fetches the data from the API and store it in `questionsArray`. Using the questionsArray, I print the very first question as a heading, as you can see from this code `{questionsArray[0]? <h1>{questionsArray[0].question}</h1> : ''}`.

[image]

This is how my `questionsArray` looks like. Now I want to generate 4 dynamic buttons for now that contains the answers in them. Now since there are two values of answers, one correct and other an array of incorrect answers, I am not able to think of how can I print these buttons in a random way, like the correct answer shouldn't be lets say the first option. I want it to be random, i.e. it can be either first button, or second button, third button, or fourth button. How do I achieve it?

Comment: You can put correct and incorrect answers in a single array and use lodash shuffle method to shuffle them around: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle
Then you can just render the buttons by mapping over that array

Comment: anyone put bounty for this question? hahaha

Comment: @szczocik How can I put correct and incorrect answer in a single array?

Comment: ```const allAnswers = [questionArray[0].correct_answer, ...questionArray[0].incorrect_answers]```
Something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary array to store all the answer together (correct and incorrect) and render based on this array. You should put the correct answer in a random position of this array with [Math.random()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_random.asp) like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";

const axios = require("axios").default;

const PlayQuiz = () => {
  // declaring all the state here
  const [questionsArray, setQuestionsArray] = useState([]);

  // Using effects here
  useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10"
    })
      .then((res) => {
        setQuestionsArray(Object.values(res.data)[1]);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("questions array", questionsArray);
  }, [questionsArray]);

  const getAnswers = (q) => {
    const temp = [...q.incorrect_answers];
    const randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * (temp.length + 1));
    temp.splice(randomPosition, 0, q.correct_answer);
    return temp;
  };
  // Returning html markup here
  return (
    <>
      <div className="questions-container">
        {questionsArray[0] ? (
          <div>
            <h1>{questionsArray[0].question}</h1>
            {getAnswers(questionsArray[0]).map((a) => {
              return <button key={a}>{a}</button>;
            })}
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PlayQuiz;
```

You can see it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-hooks-jx16n?file=/src/PlayQuiz.js:0-1245)